# Parallel Web Service Calls in Java

Tags: java, web-services, parallel-processing

Is there anyway to make web service calls from a Java client app. (Apache Axis based) in parallel? Does async style Web Service client (Apache Axis based) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-axis2/
http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/12/axis2-async

And a thing you can do in your client is to simply start new Threads that call the web-service.